# Can value of a public variable in Solidity be called and returned by web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps

How to get value of a public variable in Solidity be called and returned by web3?

Comment: web3 v0 - `contractInstance.variableName()`. web3 v1 - `contractInstance.methods.variableName().call()`.

Comment: Just curious..is there a reason you didn't put it in answer?

Comment: @logeekal he/she never does ;P